# Show "You need to choose options for your item" message in magento2.2 when I hit API for add to cart configrable product

Tags: json, magento2.2, rest-api

> **This is on Magento official document**
>
> http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/get-started/order-tutorial/order-add-items.html
>
> magento-host/rest/default/V1/carts/mine/items

**parameters**

```
{
  "cartItem": {
    "sku": "MH01",
    "qty": 1,
    "quote_id":  4,
    "product_option": {
      "extension_attributes": {
        "configurable_item_options": [
          {
            "option_id": "93",
            "option_value": 52
          },
          {
            "option_id": "141",
            "option_value": 168
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "extension_attributes": {}
  }
}
```

> **Show response** "message": "You need to choose options for your item.",

Comment: Seems in your magento don't have 168 attribute for color. In my system it's showing 147.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check attribute id which you are using in api is valid or not.

```
 {
  "cartItem": {
    "sku": "MH10",
    "qty": 1,
    "quote_id": "25",
    "product_type" : "configurable",
    "product_option": {
      "extension_attributes": {
        "configurable_item_options": [
          {
            "option_id": "93",
            "option_value": 51
          },
          {
            "option_id": "147",
            "option_value": 169
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can use above code for configurable product add in cart. It's working well in my side.

Comment: Works fine... Cheers.